# Trouble hiding/showing inline SVG in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, svg

I'm trying to use inline SVG for our icons. Specifically I am:

- Combining all svg's into an svg sprite with grunt
- Referencing them inline with the `<use>` tag ala [this article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/)

For the most part things are working well. However, I've run into problems on iOS browsers when I try to hide/show them with JS - http://codepen.io/meanspa/pen/vEGERZ

```
  $('.expand-link').click(function(){
  $('.expand-link').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Because for this codepen the SVG definitions are in the DOM it works fine as-is, but if you move them  to an external file and try to use it in mobile Safari, the SVG that's hidden originally (.icon-contract) won't display when you click on it. In fact, the only way I've found to make this work is to set .icon-contract to `display:block` initially, and then set a delay in JS so that it hides it after a few hundred milliseconds.

So just to summarize, it looks like in mobile Safari:

- If you're using the `<use>` tag to reference svg's in an external file
- And if some of those are `display:none` when the page loads
- Then they can't be displayed with JS after the fact

Has anybody else run into this problem?

Thanks.

**Update:** As Salmonface pointed out, only noticing this on iOS 7 and older, looks like it's fixed in newer versions.

Comment: I am having this problem too, but only managed to replicate it on iPhone 4 running iOS 7. It seems to have been fixed in later versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier posted [this workaround](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/swapping-out-svg-icons-problems-with-mobile-safari/):

Use "width:0px; height:0px;" instead of "display:none".

Working great for me so far.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue in cases where the svg is a child of an element with `display: none;` – e.g. within a modal.

Comment: For some reason I didn't notice this comment until now - good point, unmarking this as the answer since it's incomplete for these cases.